# Replace symbol (with a condition) on PHP

Tags: php

how correctly make on php ?
If set range have small letters -> replace them on big.

---

```
length of string - const
number of symbols from 0
set range : [4,6]
```

Example :

```
17xG2v9Hj5    ->    17xG2V9Hj5  
b7qfK5yte9    ->    b7qfK5Yte9
```

---

My code :

```
$m = '17xG2v9Hj5';

$s1 = mb_substr($m, 0, 4);      // -> 17xG
$s2 = mb_substr($m, 4, 3);      // -> 2v9
$ss = ucwords(strtoupper($s2)); // -> 2V9
$s3 = mb_substr($m, 7,3);       // -> Hj5

$my = $s1.$ss.$s3;              // -> 17xG2V9Hj5

var_dump($m).'<br/>';

var_dump($s1).'<br/>';
var_dump($s2).'<br/>';
var_dump($ss).'<br/>';
var_dump($s3).'<br/>';

var_dump($my).'<br/>';// ??? ['<br/>'] for [var_dump()] 
                      // don't work;
```

---

```
String : [a-z] and [0-9]. 
It is possible to make more shortly and faster?
```

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for posting examples and other additional details, but what is the problem you are facing? Are you getting any errors in your code? If yes, include details of it in your question. Is it with the last line of code?

Comment: About replace (with a condition) : Is my code good enough or it's possible to make more shortly and faster ?

Comment: I assumed you want to uppercase the letters in a certain position in the source-string (my answer below is based on that assumption) Is that correct? Or is you question about the behaviour of var_dump and `br`

Comment: On var_dump Andrew has answered : echo '<br/>';

Comment: Yes, but was that your main question or was it about uppercasing parts of a string?

Comment: Main question - is my code good.  String : [a-z] and [0-9]. 
It is possible to make more shortly and faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `substr_replace` to do this in one round (Assuming range and string-length are fixed)

```
$in = '17xG2v9Hj5';

var_dump(substr_replace($in, mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($in, 4, 3)), 4, 3));
```

A multibyte variant of the substr_replace function can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#94220)

*Answer below is based on [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24476155/1) of the question assuming a more general solution is wanted*

Naive solution but should work if I understood your question correctly:

```
<?php

$in = '17xG2v9Hj5';
$range = [4,6];
var_dump(uc_range($in, $range));


function uc_range($string, array $range) {
    if(!is_string($string)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$string is supposed to be a string');
    }
    $chars = str_split_unicode($string);
    foreach(range($range[0], $range[1]) as $keyIndex) {
        if(isset($chars[$keyIndex])) {
            $chars[$keyIndex] = mb_strtoupper($chars[$keyIndex]);
        }
    }
    return implode("", $chars);  
}

// see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Rangad.
Very much : var_dump(substr_replace($in, mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($in, 4, 3)), 4, 3));

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve?

`var_dump` is typically used for debug purposes, its output will be more readable if wrapped in `<pre></pre>` tags.

```
var_dump($my).'<br/>';
```

Will not actually append `'<br/>'` to the output of `var_dump` it will append it the the value **returned** by `var_dump`, in this case `void`

ie.

```
$out = var_dump($my).'<br/>'; //$out == '<br/>'
```

If you want to output `<br/>` after `var_dump` you must echo it separately.

ie.

```
var_dump($my);
echo '<br/>';
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.

Yes, clearly : echo '<br/>';

Comment: About replace (with a condition) :
    ----------------------------------------
    17xG2v9Hj5    ->    17xG2V9Hj5 // v -> V
    b7qfK5yte9    ->    b7qfK5Yte9 // y -> Y
    ----------------------------------------

Is my code good enough or it's possible to make more shortly and faster ?